# Dynamic transclude value in Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have a directive like this:

```
platform.directive("permission", function(){
  return {
   restrict: 'E',
   transclude: false,
   template: ""
  }
});
```

And i want to create a var for transclude value and change depend on conditions, How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, set `transclude: true`. This will tell angular to allow wrapping your directive outside of arbitrary content, while allowing access to the parent scope.

Normally you would use `ngTransclude` to tell angular where to put the transcluded content. Because you want more control, you would have to define a transclude function yourself, as part of your directive controller, or compile functions.

For more info, see the [transclusion documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#transclusion).